# Как заставить работать в Wordpress вложенные шорткоды?

Tags: php, wordpress

Как заставить работать в Wordpress вложенные шорткоды, когда один shortcode вложен в другой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого существует синтаксис

```
[a] [b]... [/b][/a]
```

Многие шорткоды в плагинах могут использовать такой синтаксис. Чтобы ваш шорткод работал с таким синтаксисом, его надо этому "научить".

Вот выдержка рабочего кода с одного из моих сайтов:

```
function map_shortcode( $atts, $content, $tag ) {

    if ( $content ) {
        $content = do_shortcode( $content );
        // Shortcode is called as [map][/map]
        // Call itself in [map ...] form
        // This is for a case when nested shortcodes are inside of this shortcode
        return do_shortcode( '[map ' . $content . ']' );
    }

    $objects = array();
    foreach ( $atts as $key => $value ) {
        if ( 'object' === substr( $key, 0, 6 ) ) {
            $objects[] = $value;
        }
    }

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'center'            => 'auto',
        'zoom'              => 'auto',
        'width'             => '100%',
        'height'            => '400px',
        'marker'            => '',
        'marker_size'       => '',
        'marker_hover'      => '',
        'marker_hover_size' => '',
        'marker_click'      => '',
        'marker_click_size' => '',
        'title'             => '',
        'key'               => '',
    ), $atts );

    // ... код шорткода с формированием html-строки $output

    return $output;
}

add_shortcode( 'map', 'map_shortcode' );
```

В коде проверяется, не пустой ли аргумент $content в вызове. Если не пустой, значит, шорткод вызван в стиле `[map]...[/map]`. В этом случае внутри контента раскрываются вложенные шорткоды с помощью `do_shortcode( $content )` и шорткод вызывает сам себя уже в более привычном формате `[map ...]`.

Пример использования:

```
[map]height="375px" zoom="16" marker="/wp-content/themes/моя-тема/marker.svg" marker_size="35, 25.33" marker_hover_size="42, 30.39" marker_click_size="42, 30.39" key="ключ-Google-API" object1="'[dealer_title]', '[dealer_address]', '[dealer_coordinates]'"[/map]
```

Как видим, внутри шорткода `[map]...[/map]` вложено 3 простых шорткода.